# AWS SNS Failed Notifications logging

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, failed, amazon-sns

I had some sns topics which is used for push notification.I want to enable sns topic logging for failed deliveries. Anyone have idea how can i achieve this ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add more detail. What fails regarding SNS? Is it not reaching SNS, is SNS not delivering an SMS / email, etc. This could help people help you.

Comment: we are delivering android push notifications via apps using SNS topic. Our purpose is to track the failed notifications and unsubscribe the user.

Comment: Can you please **edit the question** to give enough information for people to help you. Right now it's too vague and imprecise for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Basically I want to enable sns topic logging for failed deliveries with the help of which i know why some of notifications not delivered to the subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

The [AWS documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-failed-sns-deliveries/) describes how to turn on SNS failure logging.

1. Open the Amazon SNS console.
2. Open the left navigation menu, expand Mobile, and then choose Push notifications.
3. Under Platform applications, select the platform application you want to enable delivery status for, and then choose Edit.
4. Expand Delivery status logging – optional, and then choose Create new service role.
5. Choose Create new roles. The AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) console opens in a new tab or window.
6. On the IAM console permission request page, choose Allow.
7. Choose Save changes.